# Update: You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have two queries for oracle. And i need to modify them for mysql.
First query:

```
 UPDATE tec_onoff_file a
 SET emailtype = 'MIGR'
 WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
       FROM tec_onoff_file
       WHERE emailtype = 'MIGR'
       AND a.acctnbr = acctnbr
       AND a.magabbr = magcodes);
```

I changed it to

```
update tec_onoff_file t1
join tec_onoff_file t2
    on t2.emailtype='MIGR'
    and t1.acctnbr=t2.acctnbr
    and t1.magabbr=t2.magcodes
    set t1.emailtype='MIGR';
```

and it works.
But second query is harder for me

```
update tec_onoff_file a
set emailtype = 'REIN'
where transtype = 'REIN'
and curracctnbr not in (select curracctnbr from tec_onoff_file b
    where emailtype ='RENW'
    and a.curracctnbr=b.curracctnbr);
```

Could someone help with it? I'm trying change it like first query with JOIN, but it fails, i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Provide the query that you tried

Comment: To me, the second query logic looks no different from `update tec_onoff_file a
set emailtype = 'REIN'
where transtype = 'REIN'
and (emailtype is NULL or emailtype !='RENW')`.

Comment: @Slowcoder Thanks you too, your query is easier and gives same result as query from Strawberry. Now i know, that i need learn more about sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tec_onoff_file a
  LEFT 
  JOIN tec_onoff_file n
    ON b.curracctnbr = a.curracctnbr 
   AND b.emailtype ='RENW'
   SET emailtype = 'REIN'
 WHERE a.transtype = 'REIN'
   AND b.transtype IS NULL;
```

Comment: An explanation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, it works, but i'm not understand, why
 AND b.transtype IS NULL; ?

Comment: This is simple exclusion join. The IS NULL statement simply returns rows from the table's first instance for which there are no corresponding rows in its second.